# Disabling Session Affinity in Azure - how to effectively test before making the change

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an Azure AppService which uses session state but does so using Redis.
In *theory*, I should be able to disable "Session affinity" via the configuration tab of the app service.

**How can I test and validate to be 100% sure this is ok before disabling session affinity?**

I have a regression test suite which I can use.

*But how can I guarantee that when this test suite runs, it will use both (or more) of the instances of the app service plan?*

Background info:

We are not using an Application Gateway